# IPTABLES openvpn external ip

Tags: ubuntu

I have a server and all clients communicate with vpn to the server (tun0) 10.33.0.1

I would like to use the external ip to the server(123.45.67.8) port 5678

this is a panel
http://123.45.67.8:5678 
the above link
I want to open only to those who have connection with vpn
I would like to filter the iptables connections from openvpn 
how cann i make it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial. You leave out a lot of info (OS, home network/co-located) but this is a good start.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score -1):

i have allready openvpn install

I want to block all ip from outside

Except the users of vpn To use the outside IP from server  http://123.45.67.8:5678